# What do the error codes / error values / statuses mean in C?

Tags: c, error-handling

I know that:

- Returning 0 means the program successfully executed.
- Returning -1 means the program failed to execute properly.
- You can return with your own exit code and make it mean whatever you want with e.g. exit(69)

I have searched on the internet and also found something around **operating systems having their own error codes** such as Linux having error codes from `0 to 255`, and Windows (the operating system I am using) using error codes in the format `0xc0000000` (correct me if I'm wrong on any of this.)

However when I am using Code::Blocks IDE, I have **two** error codes/values, for example:

> Process returned with status -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

I searched for `0xC0000374` and found that it meant heap corruption, so it was useful.

However searching for an almost random number of `-1073740940` got me nowhere, so ***IN GENERAL* what is this value?** Why, when the program has to be terminated due to some error, does this value have to be so large and random?
Is it some variable inside the program that got corrupted due to some undefined behavior? **Where did it come from?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-1073740940` is signed decimal representation of hexadecimal `0xC0000374`

Comment: _Returning -1 means the program failed to execute properly._ No [on POSIX systems at least]: You can't really return a [meaningful] negative number. Generally, returning `1` (_not_ `-1`) means error. Most programs return `0/1` but the error code is actually wide open. See `man rsync` for the approx. 20 errors it can return. Windows error codes are a totally different kettle of fish, however.

Comment: In contrast to what I wrote in my previous comment, which I have now deleted, after doing some further research, I have found out that you are correct that on Windows, all NTSTATUS values that represent errors start with `0xC`. See [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) for further information. There are other NTSTATUS values that do not start with `0xC`, but these represent success, informational or warning codes, not error codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two values you're seeing in this case are identical.

The decimal value -1073740940, when represented as a 32-bit two's complement value in hexadecimal is 0xC0000374.  The value is just being displayed two different ways.